# Why are ampersands escaped when generating url with link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my simple rails 3 code :

```
<%= link_to "link", gateway_index_url(developer:@item.developer.api_key, tracker:"email", url:@product.url) %>
```

And the result is :

```
<a href="/gateway?developer=abcde&amp;tracker=email&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bla.fr%2FproductA" >link</a>
```

The problem is that `&` are rewritten in `&amp;`. I can't figure how to prevent escaping, as `:escape => false` doesn't exist in Rails 3

Comment: The generated markup is the correct way to write a link URL with ampersands in it. Browsers will understand URLs with unescaped ampersands, but they are technically incorrect. If you View Source in Firefox and find the HTML for a link with unescaped ampersands, you will see the ampersands are highlighted in red as an error.

Comment: You mean that /foo?a=1&b=2 is incorrect and should always be written as /foo?a=1&amp;b=2 ?

Comment: Exactly. As described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1911482/578288), all element attributes in HTML should escape `&`, `"`, `'`, and a few other characters. The `href` attribute of the `a` element is no exception.

Comment: Just wow. We learn every day :)

Comment: Interesting it should be that way. Unfortunately my gmail can't read my unescaped link in my HTML mail

Comment: Here's the WDG's explanation for this: http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: So here's the source

```
  def link_to(*args, &block)
    if block_given?
      options      = args.first || {}
      html_options = args.second
      link_to(capture(&block), options, html_options)
    else
      name         = args[0]
      options      = args[1] || {}
      html_options = args[2]

      html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)
      url = url_for(options)

      href = html_options['href']
      tag_options = tag_options(html_options)

      href_attr = "href=\"#{ERB::Util.html_escape(url)}\"" unless href
      "<a #{href_attr}#{tag_options}>#{ERB::Util.html_escape(name || url)}</a>".html_safe
    end
  end
```

As we can see, from the source, this behavior is by design.

You can try one of two solutions, I haven't tried them but they should work

1.) Try placing the call to gateway inside of a call to #raw:

```
<%= link_to "link", raw(gateway_index_url(developer: @item.developer.api_key, tracker:"email", url:@product.url)) %>
```

That may solve your specific problem, an the second approach, while a bit more brute-force should also work...

2.) If you want to convert it (the whole href) back you can... use CGI::unescape_html:

```
<%= CGI::unescape_html(link_to "link", gateway_index_url(developer: @item.developer.api_key, tracker:"email", url:@product.url)) %>
```

Good luck, hopefully this helps.

Update 2: Fixed call to cgi unescape, was using "." when it should be "::" and formatting fix. Forgot to indent example for #1

Answer (score 1):

Rory O'Kane is spot on. The answer to "Why are ampersands escaped when generating url with link_to?" is that is the correct way to separate params in a url.

Is there a problem with the url the way it is?
If so, could you elaborate on the problem?

You may be able to prevent escaping the url by using `raw` on the entire url like so:

```
<%= link_to "link", raw(gateway_index_url(developer:@item.developer.api_key, tracker:"email", url:@product.url)) %>
```

Comment: I just didnt know it was like this. Never, never wrote my urls this way